# passing through firewall in htmlunit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am creating something on htmlunit to read content of webpage. However I am working on netwer where firewall is enabled. I have my Credential that i can use to pass through the firewall(we use this credential to access internet). I am not sure where to configure this. 
I tried the below but it didn't work. Any thoughts?

```
public class Sparsh {
private WebClient  webClient;
private final String userName,password,loginUrl="https://www.google.com";

public Sparsh(String userName,String password)

{
    this.userName=userName;
    this.password=password;
    webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

DefaultCredentialsProvider cp = (DefaultCredentialsProvider)webClient.getCredentialsProvider();
cp.addCredentials("user", "password");
//cp.addProxyCredentials("myuser", "mypasswd");
webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

}


public boolean loginCheck() throws IOException
{
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(loginUrl);
System.out.println(page.asText());

if (page.asText().contains("Service Catalog"))
    {
        return true;
    }
return false;
} public static void main(String[] Arg) throws IOException
{
  Sparsh snow=new Sparsh("xxxxxx","xxxxxx");
  snow.loginCheck();
  snow.close();
}
}
```

I am getting below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: www.google.com
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:876)   at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:876)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1229)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1180)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1110)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1046)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:44)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:102)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:314)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:85)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:179)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1297)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1214)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:325)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:394)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:379)
at Authentication.Sparsh.loginCheck(Sparsh.java:59)
at Authentication.Sparsh.main(Sparsh.java:113)
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to access google.com from your browser on this machine? If yes, then try setting proxy.

```
webClient.getOptions.setProxyConfig(new ProxyConfig(proxy_host, proxy_port));
```

Proxy user/password should be same as the credentials you use for machine (AD credentials for example).

Make sure to add domain-name to your user name.